# Pronunciation for אלוהים הוא אלוהים שלי

Tags: hebrew, names, pronunciation

I got this from translating 'G-d is my G-d' on Google Translate. However I don't know how to pronounce the Hebrew. Can somebody give me the pronunciation on this and is there a Hebrew name that means the same thing.

Comment: Eliahu (Elijah) He is my G-d.  Try not to learn too much Hebrew from Google translate.

Comment: @YDK, +1,000,000 on your comment!

Answer (score 4):

It is pronounced *elohim hu elohim sheli*, but it sounds strange and tautological in Hebrew. There are Hebrew names that mean approximately the same thing, like Yoel (Joel in English) and Eliyahu (Elijah). *Yoel* literally means "Ya [a divine name] is El [a divine name]", while *eliyahu* might be translated "Yahu [a divine name] is my god".

Perhaps what you are looking for is something like what Moses tells the Israelites in Deuteronomy 4:39, that "*adonai hu ha'elohim*": "The LORD [the divine, four-lettered name] is God."

Comment: In case anybody is wondering, I say that *eliyahu* only might be translated as "Yahu is my god" because, in actual fact, the *yud* is a petrified case ending and not a first-person suffix. While people might interpret it today as "Yahu is my god", it originally meant, "Yahu is El". Not relevant to my answer, I don't think, but interesting.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I believe (though I could be mistaken) the word El means G-d (it is _treated_ as a Divine name, but it means the same thing as Elohim, in the sense that it means the-all-powerful-being-fit-to-be-worshipped. Second, the _waw_ at the end of Eliyahu is also a case ending (hence the abbreviated form appearing as Eliyah, likely the source of the transliteration of Elijah). And it's not like case endings have no meaning, either. They imply gender and assign properties to the word (in this case its parts). I posit that Eliyahu _does_, in fact, mean Y"K is my G-d. ...

Comment: ... or at the very least, it means Y"K is G-d.

Comment: An interesting issue, and I see a lot of scope here for difference of opinion. Personally, I don't consider El and Elohim to be synonymous in the earlier literature. There were lots of different names for God (or lots of different gods, if you prefer). Some people (and some places) have names with El, some with Yah(u), some with Hadad, and some with Baal. Part of the genius of Israelite monotheism was in its syncretism: Yah *is* El; El *is* Baal; etc. In standard grammars of Biblical Hebrew, this is how those names are translated, despite it not being how they are later understood.

Comment: I used to think אליהו meant the same as אליהוא (from Iyov)

Comment: At the end of the day, though, I can't think of a name more equivalent in meaning, for purposes of the question, than Eliyahu.

Answer (score 2):

Pronunciation transcribed using letters in another alphabet is always ambiguous. [The existing (good) answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18842), by Shimon bM, writes *elohim hu elohim sheli*, but, then, you don't know whether that initial *e* is pronounced as in *e-mail* or as in *end* or as in *fiance*. The right way to transcribe pronunciation is using a phonetic alphabet, either [the International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) or [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII-IPA) [other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAMPA); the IPA is the most 'official' standard. Even using such a phonetic alphabet, there's still ambiguity, because every symbol represents a range of sounds, but the ambiguity is far less.

So here goes (in IPA).

In a modern Israeli accent, אלוהים הוא אלוהים שלי (actually, properly, אלהים הוא אלהים שלי‎), is /ɛloˈhim ˈhu ɛloˈhim ʃɛˈliː/. (Modern Israeli Hebrew doesn't really have distinct /e/ and /ɛ/, so what I transcribed as /ɛ/ others might transcribe as /e/.)

In my own (Americanized Ashkenazi) accent, it's /ɛlowˈhɪm ˈhuw ɛlowˈhɪm ʃɛˈlij/.

Some might say /ɛlojˈhɪm ˈhiː ɛlojˈhɪm ʃɛˈliː/.

Comment: also, many [modern Israelis pronounce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Hebrew_phonology) ה closer to [/ʔ/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%94) than to /h/, so it can be anywhere from what this answer states through /ɛloˈʔim ˈʔu ɛloˈʔim ʃɛˈliː/ or even dropped entirely, like: /ɛloˈ.im ˈ.u ɛloˈ.im ʃɛˈliː/, though that is not necessarily "proper".

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, yeah, good point. Or really, I think, [/∅/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_%28linguistics%29).